# socket.to(roomId).emit not working after reconnect

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'd like to explain a problem I've been facing the last days and I'm not able to solve. I'm working with socket.io, using rooms to emit to multiple clients. I am testing the situation in which one reconnects (due to wi-fi connection failure for example).

The situation is the following:
Client side:

```
socket.on('reconnect', function () {
    var socketId = socket.id;
    socket.emit('reconnectAttempt',{
        id: $matchId,
        username: $username,
        socketId: socketId
    });
    log("you were reconnected");
});
```

Server Side:

```
socket.on('reconnectAttempt',function(data){
    listClientsInRoom(data.id);
    socket.join(data.id); // Since socket.id changes after reconnect
    listClientsInRoom(data.id);
    socket.to(data.id).emit('reconnect attempt succeeded');
};
```

Where:

```
function listClientsInRoom(key){
    var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[key].sockets;
    console.log('___Clients in room:'+JSON.stringify(clients));
}
```

and the output is something like (In this case only one client which reconnects):

```
___Clients in room:{"mfA-h4IkTtUMgPNsAAAD":true}
___Clients in room:{"mfA-
h4IkTtUMgPNsAAAD":true,"ShdVRVzVr4x4WCggAAAE":true}
```

In this case, being ShdVRVzVr4x4WCggAAAE the socket.id after the reconnect event.
Then, with this situation, it seems that the socket has been properly added 
to the room, but as you can see, after joining, i do :

```
socket.to(data.id).emit('reconnect attempt succeeded');
```

This should just do a log in the client side (In all the room), and works in all clients except the one that reconnected. If i do :

```
socket.emit('reconnect attempt succeeded');
```

instead, I will see the log correctly.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake, was just trying with this 'reconnect attempt succeeded' event, which as can be seen in the question is wrong called.

Question:

```
socket.to(data.id).emit('reconnect attempt succeeded');
```

Correct way

```
io.to(data.id).emit('reconnect attempt succeeded');
```